# Creating a combo chart by using Python and win32com

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I need to generate a combo chart from Excel data, by using a Python program based on win32com. I have problems to write the correct code because the Microsoft API reference is intended for VBA and it is not always easy to understand which is the equivalent Python code.

I have no problems to create two separated charts by using AddChart2() method, but I have problems to combine them.

To create two separate charts it is easy. For example, a scatter chart is created by

```
  chart_ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, win32c.xlXYScatter, 0, 0, 480, 480).Select()
  scatter_chart = wb.ActiveChart
```

whereas a 100% Column Stacked chart is created by

```
  chart_ws.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, win32c.xlColumnStacked100, 0, 0, 480, 480).Select()
  stacked_chart = wb.ActiveChart
```

Note that chart_ws is simply a worksheet to allocate charts. I created it in advance.
Once I have any chart I can add series of data as follows

```
  series = any_chart.SeriesCollection(1).NewSeries()
  series.Values = [...] # A list of values, for example, from an Excel Range
```

This work very well.

Now I am trying to create a single combined chart and I tried

```
  chart_ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, win32c.xlXYScatter, 0, 0, 480, 480).Select()

  # Set combo chart properties
  chart = wb.ActiveChart
  chart.HasTitle = True
  chart.ChartTitle.Text = "My Combo Chart"

  # Here I try to set the first chart
  chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = win32c.xlXYScatter # Redundant?
  chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1

  # Here is where I create a series for scatter chart
  series = chart.SeriesCollection(1).NewSeries() # Only one series of (X,Y) data
  series.Name = "Scatter Data"
  series.XValues = [...] # A list of values
  series.Values = [...] # A list of values

  # Here I try to set the second chart (no title)
  chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = win32c.xlColumnStacked100 # Necessary
  chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2

  # Here is where I create two series for column stacked chart
  series = chart.SeriesCollection(2).NewSeries() # First series for stacked columns
  series.Values = [...] # A list of values
  series = chart.SeriesCollection(2).NewSeries() # Second series for stacked columns
  series.Values = [...] # A list of values
```

However I get an error that it is typical of wrong usage of API

```
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'S', 'Parameter not valid', None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

So, my code is wrong. No surprise, but I have some difficulties to understand why and where. The API Reference Manual has no examples to support me. I spent some time to search in the web some example, but I found nothing useful to me.

Any help appreciated. I hope I was clear to describe the problem.

Comment: Which line is triggering the error? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I get no info from PyCharm about which is the offending instruction. That is why I was confused. However, after several hours of work, I eventually found a solution. I am posting it as an answer, in case someone else has the same problem. It is really a pity that the win32com API reference includes only VBA examples and not also Python ones. Sometimes it si not so easy to map the instructions between the two different languages.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I made several attempts to figure out what the right solution was and in the end I got there. The trick is to **not** create two different chart's series collections, but **only one**, and to associate the `ChartType` and `AxisGroup` properties directly to the individual series. This code works fine, and I post it here in case it could be useful to someone else.

```
  chart_ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, win32c.xlXYScatter, 0, 0, 480, 480).Select()

  # Set combo chart properties
  chart = wb.ActiveChart
  chart.HasTitle = True
  chart.ChartTitle.Text = "My Combo Chart"

  # Here is where I create a series for scatter chart
  series = chart.SeriesCollection().NewSeries() # Only one series of (X,Y) data
  series.AxisGroup = win32c.xlPrimary
  series.ChartType = win32c.xlXYScatter
  series.Name = "Scatter Data"
  series.XValues = [...] # A list of values
  series.Values = [...] # A list of values

  # Here is where I create two series for column stacked chart
  series = chart.SeriesCollection().NewSeries() # First series for stacked columns
  series.AxisGroup = win32c.xlSecondary
  series.ChartType = win32c.xlColumnStacked100
  series.Values = [...] # A list of values
  series = chart.SeriesCollection().NewSeries() # Second series for stacked columns
  series.AxisGroup = win32c.xlSecondary
  series.ChartType = win32c.xlColumnStacked100
  series.Values = [...] # A list of values
```